# How to clear gradle cache?

Tags: android, caching, intellij-idea, ide, gradle

I'm trying to use Android Studio, and the first time I boot it up, it takes like 45 MINUTES to compile... If I don't quit the application, it is okay - each subsequent compilation/running the app will take around 45 seconds.

I've tried to check some of my caches: there's a `.gradle/caches` folder in my home directory, and it's contains 123 MB.

There's also a `.gradle` folder in my project folder... one of the `taskArtifacts` was like 200 MB. I'm scared to just randomly nuke them both. What parts of the folders are safe to delete?

Is there a better explanation for why my Android Studio is taking forever to run the `gradle assemble` task upon first time loading the application?

Do I also have to clear the intellij cache too?

Comment: i found out later that the 45 minutes to compile is because i changed the settings for `Compiler -> Gradle` to not `Use in-process build`. nothing to do with the cache

Comment: None of the answers helped. Turns out some images got corrupted. Opening the images in Windows Explorer quickly shows you which images are corrupted (the ones which it doesn't load previews for). Replaced those images and voila!

Comment: @david-t Could you point to this option's whereabouts? I have version *3.3.1* but cannot find it under *Preferences - Build, Execution, Deployment*

Comment: `./gradlew clean build --no-build-cache` will force a project build without using the build cache.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

As @Bradford20000 pointed out in the comments, there might be a `gradle.properties` file as well as global gradle scripts located under `$HOME/.gradle`. In such case special attention must be paid when deleting the content of this directory.

The `.gradle/caches` directory holds the `Gradle` build cache. So if you have any error about build cache, you can delete it.

The [--no-build-cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_enable) option will run gradle without the build cache.

**Daemon on MS Windows**
If you're on Windows, you'll need to kill the daemon before it allows you to clear those directories. See [Kill all Gradle Daemons Regardless Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189630/kill-all-gradle-daemons-regardless-version) for more info.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you have a gradle.properties file in your .gradle folder in your home directory, you will not want to delete the whole folder. Typically, just deleting .gradle/caches is enough to get Gradle to redownload all dependencies.

Comment: with every update to Android Studio, gradle builds seem to get slower and slower. Why is it that when I deploy to device, stop app running, and then deploy again (without touching any code at all!) that Android studio once again takes 2 minutes to make a build and deploy it. It's friggin nutz.

Comment: On Android Studio to clean out the system caches: Android stdio main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.and build menu >clean project

Comment: If you're on Windows, you'll need to kill the daemon first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189630/kill-all-gradle-daemons-regardless-version

Comment: --no-build-cache on windows appears to do nothing

Answer (score 711):

**Gradle** cache is located at

- On Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches`
- On Mac / UNIX: `~/.gradle/caches/`

You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run

```
rm -r $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

on UNIX system. Run this command will also force to download dependencies.

---

#### UPDATE

[Clear the **Android** build cache of current project](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html)

NOTE: Android Studio's `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` doesn't clear the Android build cache, so you'll have to clean it separately.

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

On Mac or UNIX:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

#### UPDATE 2

This article [Put your Android Studio on a diet](https://medium.com/back-market-engineering/put-your-android-studio-on-a-diet-fa4d364acb05) gives more details on Android Studio caches

Comment: This did not clear the cache of a maven dependency. I deleted the library from the maven repository and invalidated the Android Studio caches, but the project still builds. This means the gradle cache for the maven dependency is not cleared.

Comment: The way you described will only clean cache from the main project and it's project dependencies, but the library dependencies are intact. You described how to clean AndroidStudio's cache, but not gradle's cache.

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't appear on Mac before I load the project.

Comment: it still works well on the latest version Android Studio

Comment: I manually had to delete the cache folder inside the userdir / .gradle folder

Comment: you probably don't want to dump the entire cache dir, just the build-cache. use `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-1` instead. if you need to have gradle re download dependencies invoke the build with --refresh-dependencies

Comment: if you want clean and clean cache, run both task: `gradlew clean cleanBuildCache`

Comment: In my case, I had also to remove `app/build` directory along with gradle cache `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`

Comment: i was getting 403 and response was cached. this worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the Gradle cache is located in a different place on Windows.

Comment: If you are so desperate that you came here - and using expo - try to 1. fix all package incompatibilites (except non-important like icons) 2. make sure you have JDK (java) installed - the version it tries to use - on ubuntu - e.g. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk` (no just linking android SDK and having the appropriate SDK API version installed is not enough)

Comment: I had some 4GB of extra trash after a failed expo modules build. It was located in `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/.temp`

Comment: `cleanBuildCache` longer works, use `rm -rf $GRADLE_HOME/caches/build-cache-*` instead as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43245885/481061

Answer (score 126):

### UPDATE

`cleanBuildCache` no longer works.

Android Gradle plugin now utilizes Gradle cache feature
https://guides.gradle.org/using-build-cache/

> **TO CLEAR CACHE**
>
> **Clean the cache directory to avoid any hits from previous builds**
>
> ```
>  rm -rf $GRADLE_HOME/caches/build-cache-*
> ```

https://guides.gradle.org/using-build-cache/#caching_android_projects

**Other digressions:** see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache/55717269#55717269) (including edits).

---

### === OBSOLETE INFO ===

Newest solution using Gradle task:

```
cleanBuildCache
```

Available via Android plugin for Gradle, revision 2.3.0 (February 2017)

Dependencies:

1. Gradle 3.3 or higher.
2. Build Tools 25.0.0 or higher.

More info at:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html#clear_the_build_cache

### Background

***Build cache***
Stores certain outputs that the Android plugin generates when building your project (such as unpackaged AARs and pre-dexed remote dependencies). Your clean builds are much faster while using the cache because the build system can simply reuse those cached files during subsequent builds, instead of recreating them. Projects using Android plugin 2.3.0 and higher use the build cache by default. To learn more, read Improve Build Speed with Build Cache.

NOTE: The cleanBuildCache task is not available if you disable the build cache.

### USAGE

Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Linux / Mac:

```
gradle cleanBuildCache
```

Android Studio / IntelliJ:

```
gradle tab (default on right) select and run the task or add it via the configuration window
```

NOTE: `gradle` / `gradlew` are system specific files containing scripts. Please see the related system info how to execute the scripts:

- [Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-run-a-script-in-linux/)
- [Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613481(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html)

Comment: On windows: `del $HOME/.gradle/caches`

Answer (score 123):

Take care with gradle daemon, you have to stop it before clear and re-run gradle.

Stop first daemon:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Clean cache using:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

Run again you compilation

Comment: Can you explain why or link to some documentation on this?

Comment: If your gradle daemon is running your gradle caches will be in use. Consequently, your OS will likely prevent the deletion.

Comment: After hours of struggle... THANK MATE.
I actually belive that `./gradlew --stop` this line did everything.

Comment: This eliminated the errors for me after I ran both commands in the IDE's project's instance of the terminal

Comment: same, I was cleaning the build and the caches folder, but the project wouldn't compile. only after stopping the daemon it worked, thanks!!

Comment: Thank you! This finally solved my problems, when I removed cache manually, tried to rebuild the project and got errors related to cache all the time (even after cleaning everything).

Comment: This is a lifesaver information. If you miss this, there is a good chance that you will waste some hours trying to figure out what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 17):

My `~/.gradle/caches/` folder was using 14G.

After using the following solution, it went from 14G to 1.7G.

```bash
$ rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-*

$ rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-*
```

Bonus:

This command shows you in detail the used cache space

```bash
$ sudo du -ah --max-depth 1 ~/.gradle/caches/ | sort -hr
```

Answer (score 16):

The gradle daemon also creates a many large text files of every single build log. They are stored here:

> **`~/.gradle/daemon/X.X/daemon-XXXX.out.log`**

"X.X" is the gradle version in use, like "7.5", and "XXXX" are just random numbers, like "1234". `"~"` is your user `$HOME` folder.

**The total size can grow to several hundred MB in just a few months**. There is no way to disable the logging. The files are not automatically deleted and they do not really need to be retained.

But you can create a [small gradle task to automatically delete them](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-daemon-produces-a-lot-of-logs/9905), and free up lots of disk space:

Add this to your **`app/build.gradle`**:

```js
android {

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    // Delete large build log files from ~/.gradle/daemon/X.X/daemon-XXX.out.log
    // Source 1: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-daemon-produces-a-lot-of-logs/9905
    // Source 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache#51479044
    def gradle = project.getGradle()
    new File("${gradle.getGradleUserHomeDir().getAbsolutePath()}/daemon/${gradle.getGradleVersion()}").listFiles().each {
        if (it.getName().endsWith('.out.log')) {
            // println("Deleting gradle log file: $it") // Optional debug output
            it.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

To see which files are being deleted, you can enable the `println()` line, then see the debug output in Android Studio -> View -> Tool Windows -> Build. Then press "Toggle View" button on that window to show the text output.

**Note that a Gradle Sync or any Gradle Build will trigger the file deletions.**

A better way would be to automatically move the files to the Trash/Recycle Bin, or at least copy them to a Trash folder first. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: To send OSX items to the finder/trash instead of directly remove, this post seems to have many good ideas https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/how-to-move-files-to-trash-from-command-line

Answer (score 13):

there seems to be incorrect info posted here. some people report on how to clear the Android builder cache (with task `cleanBuildCache`) but do not seem to realize that said cache is independent of Gradle's build cache, AFAIK.

my understanding is that Android's cache predates (and inspired) Gradle's, but i could be wrong. whether the Android builder will be/was updated to use Gradle's cache and retire its own, i do not know.

**EDIT:** the Android builder cache is obsolete and has been eliminated. the Android Gradle plugin now uses Gradle's build cache instead. to control this cache you must now interact with Gradle's generic cache infrastructure.

TIP: search for Gradle's cache help online without mentioning the keyword 'android' to get help for the currently relevant cache.

**EDIT 2:** due to tir38's question in a comment below, i am testing using an Android Gradle plugin v3.4.2 project. the gradle cache is enabled by `org.gradle.caching=true` in `gradle.properties`. i do a couple of `clean build` and the second time most tasks show `FROM-CACHE` as their status, showing that the cache is working.

surprisingly, i have a `cleanBuildCache` gradle task and a `<user-home>/.android/build-cache/3.4.2/` directory, both hinting the existence of an Android builder cache.

i execute `cleanBuildCache` and the `3.4.2/` directory is gone. next i do another `clean build`:

- nothing changed: most tasks show `FROM-CACHE` as their status and the build completed at cache-enabled speeds.
- the `3.4.2/` directory is recreated.
- the `3.4.2/` directory is empty (save for 2 hidden, zero length marker files).

**conclusions:**

1. caching of all normal Android builder tasks is handled by Gradle.
2. executing `cleanBuildCache` does not clear or affect the build cache in any way.
3. there is still an Android builder cache there. this could be vestigial code that the Android build team forgot to remove, or it could actually cache something strange that for whatever reason has not or cannot be ported to using the Gradle cache. (the 'cannot' option being highly improvable, IMHO.)

next, i disable the Gradle cache by removing `org.gradle.caching=true` from `gradle.properties` and i try a couple of `clean build`:

- the builds are slow.
- all tasks show their status as being executed and not cached or up to date.
- the `3.4.2/` directory continues to be empty.

**more conclusions:**

4. there is no Android builder cache fallback for when the Gradle cache fails to hit.
5. the Android builder cache, at least for common tasks, has indeed been eliminated as i stated before.
6. the relevant [android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache) contains outdated info. in particular the cache **is not enabled by default** as stated there, and the Gradle cache has to be enabled manually.

**EDIT 3: user tir38 confirmed that the Android builder cache is obsolete and has been eliminated with [this find](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324009#comment3). tir38 also created [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148169019). thanks!**

Comment: Can you link to where you read that the Android builder cache is now obsolete and that it now uses Gradle's build cache instead?

Comment: @tir38, nope. but i updated my answer above with my own testing. thanks.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your diligent research. You confirm most of what I saw in testing too: 1. empty `3.4.2/` dir. 2. presence of `cleanBuildCache` task 3. disabling gradle build cache and rebuilding didn't show any evidence of android tasks hitting cache.

Comment: A little more poking and I got actual confirmation that android's build cache is/was rolled into gradle's https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324009#comment3 I opened a doc request to remove that doc page: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148169019

Comment: Very thorough and insightful answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

**FOR MAC or LINUX Users:**

**To clean a cache for specific project/jar:**

Find all the cache files related to that project

```
find ~/.gradle/caches -name your-project-artifact-id
```

The above command will return all the cache files related to `your-project-artifact-id` (e.g., `com.google`).

Pass the path of each result to the command below:

```
rm -rf <each file returned>
```

Finally, to pull latest artifacts, run this:

```
gradle clean install
```

**Update:**

One liner to delete the cache:

```
for file in `find ~/.gradle/caches -name yourprojectartifactid`; do `rm -rf $file`; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Latest command:

```
--no-build-cache
```

Found at: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html
Works perfectly for a command like:

```
./gradlew SomeApp:installDebug --no-build-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

This article [Put your Android Studio on a diet](https://medium.com/back-market-engineering/put-your-android-studio-on-a-diet-fa4d364acb05) helped a lot as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/13093413)

For those looking for a quick fix press on:
`File` > `Invalidate Caches Restart`

Answer (score 1):

Using the gradle commands didn't work with my projects, I kept getting failures that the commands listed above were not supported in my root project.
Deleting the directories in the cache directory worked for me.

`sudo rm -r .gradle/caches/*`

I had attempted to remove artifacts that came up in my error reports, but this provided me with a clean workspace and was able to narrow my dependency issues much easier.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue
just go to

File -> invalidate cashes then check option **Clear file system cash and local history** then click on button **invalidate and restart**
after restarting android studio should be gone. :-) GL

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33678960)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31, fixed the problem in my case. But the build was failing at 99% giving this weird error here [More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327301/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-lib-armeabi-v7a-libfbjni). Solved by the solution given.

Answer (score 0):

double shift to search for the whole project -> execute grade task -> input "gragle clean" command -> run this command

Answer (score -1):

In android studio open **View > Tool Windows > Terminal** and execute the following commands

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

if you want to disable the cache from your project add this into the gradle build properties

(***Warning**: this may slow your PC performance if there is no cache than same time will consume after every time during the run app*)

```
android.enableBuildCache=false
```

Comment: this command is obsolete, please see another comment

Answer (score -1):

I delete the content of gradel.properties (global properties) manually.
The operation is completed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

For Beginners (How to Locate Caches):

1. Close Android Studio completely.
2. Locate your project file on the computer where you store it while creating the app.  For example, I stored mine on the Desktop.
3. Open the particular app profile, then go to `.gradle` then  go to *Build Output Cleanup* where you should see the cache.
4. Delete the cache.
5. Open Android studio and run your app again.

Answer (score -3):

To clear your gradle cache in android studio:

1. open terminal and
2. run `gradlew clean`

Comment: This is incorrect.  This does not clear the Gradle cache.

Comment: Wrong answer. This command actually does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005713/difference-between-clean-gradlew-clean.

Comment: @AbdulMateen this works for windows, for linux you need ./gradlew clean

Comment: `gradlew clean` will delete a build directory, all your classes will be removed for a fresh compile. assemble will create an archive (JAR) file from your Java project and will run all other tasks that require compile, test and so on