# Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0. after SDK update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, build.gradle

After the sdk update im not able to create a hello world application.
My build.gradle looks like  this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.coders.yo"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

But build got failed  and shows

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
     Required by:
         Yo:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0
```

so i added  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.' and now i get

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
<a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I have updated the android sdk 
[image]
and the support libraries 
[image]

I have been stuck in it for the past few hours .Can some one please help me identify the issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your dependencies in build.gradle seem to be correct.

Try to clean the cache (File -> Invalidate cache and restart), then sync the gradle file and clean and build.

In your gradle file there is a strange line.
This DSL doesn't exist in last gradle plugin (which version are you using?)

```
 runProguard false
```

You should update the plugin (1.1.0), the gradle version (2.2.1) and change this line in

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: spot on! That was the exact issue.I was using Android Studio Beta 0.86. Updated  and problem got fixed

Answer (score 3):

> so i added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.'` and now i
>   get
>
> `Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.`

If you added exactly that, then I think your problem is the extra `.` at the end. :)

Try:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

Comment: No luck mate . Still Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just needed to update SDK Tools and Extras.

Answer (score 1):

[How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

This is all explained here...

Just wipe out your .gradle GLOBAL cache (caches directory)!  This was killing me for 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

As i know about this issue, It is because of version of supported library, what you need to do ,You using version that is not available with your current configuration.

1. Just delete this line from the gradle file
2. Now select your project goto module setting (Press F12)
3. Add dependency again using library dependency.

**Using above steps you are adding available version of support library.**

Answer (score 0):

If this might help someone, after MANY trials and errors, I found that I was targeting the wrong SDK version (an older one) in the build.gradle file corresponding to "library". To change this you can do it by hand or go to the Module Settings Menu (right click on your project folder -> Open Module Settings. Then in "library" - Properties you can change the Compile Sdk and the Build Tools Versions.

[image]

Obviously this worked for me after having all support libraries and building tools up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradle version like I have change 2.1 to 2.2.1 and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `implementation` instead rather than `compile` in your `dependencies` node