# How to clear Gradle scripts cache folder automatically?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an automatic APK generator which compiles Android apps using Gradle console commands. I found this problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create parent directory '/root/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/settings_14c7jxprvkvxiv2ted70j3e0u' when creating directory '/root/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/settings_14c7jxprvkvxiv2ted70j3e0u/SettingsScript/buildscript'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
java.lang.Exception: Error processing Build command. Error code: 1
```

The problem is that directory `/root/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/`has hundreds of thousands of subdirectories generated and it has reached Linux inode limit.

Why is Gradle generating all those directories and how can I tell Gradle to stop this? Would be perfect if Gradle has an option to delete/clean these cache directories automatically.

IMPORTANT: I'm not using Android Studio, all the process is automated and using console commands (gradle assembleRelease).

Comment: Are you running a `daemon`?  If so you should be able to clean up the caches by stopping the `daemon` instances with `gradle --stop`

Comment: It is not running on a daemon, it is running on a java jersey webservice. Did you mean that gradle --stop will clean .gradle cache scripts directory?

Comment: Maybe these answers will help you~: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache