# Gradle Build Failed in Android Studio (Cannot read testArtifacts.bin from cache)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

There is no error in the code. But the build fails with the following error:

```
Error:Could not read entry ':app:packageDebug' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (/Users/sibidharan/Developer/Android Dev/Karpagam/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin).
> java.io.EOFException (no error message)
```

I am using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9 on OS X 10.11.3

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Removing the project-local `.gradle` folder did it for me. It was then recreated during the next build and all was fine again.

**UPDATE:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/3073612) answer helps.

**Gradle** cache locates at

- On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches
- On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/

You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

on Unix or OS X system.

Comment: Removing the home `.gradle` directory didn't work for me, this one did.

Comment: Thanks! For me it worked with the first solution (removing project-local .gradle)

Comment: Deleting the project-local .gradle file did it for me with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2

Answer (score 1):

Step-1: clean project

Step-2: Invalidate cashes

Step-3: Go to project structure and check problems then fix the suggested issues like broken class paths.

Step-4: Go to home directory of your PC or laptop and show hidden files, here you will get .gradle file delete it permanently and then restart android studio and build the project with file downloads.

Gradle caches locates at:

On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches

On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/

You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/

on Unix or OS X system.

Note: .gradle should be deleted permanently from trash too.