# Error when running in the new Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I developed few months ago an android application that is working well. I wanted then to add some updates on the code. I updated android studio and now that I want to run my code with the new Android studio i have this error :

```
   Error:Could not read entry ':app:packageDebug' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (/Users/sofiane/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/Changes/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin).
   >com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication$DexPackagingPolicy
```

Can any one help me to fix this, i can't even understand why  ??

Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651408/gradle-build-failed-in-android-studio-cannot-read-testartifacts-bin-from-catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Solution of this problem is**

clean out the gradle system caches,
    Gradle cache locates at

```
On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches
On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

**Or 2nd solution for this problem is**

Just delete `ProjectDirectory/.gradle/taskArtifacts.bin` file and restart your Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: @Castiell try to update your gradle or else other solution is show my updated answer

Comment: can't find the taskArtifacts.bin in the .gradle/ ??

Comment: @Castiell Update my answer for getting  `taskArtifacts.bin `

Comment: @Castiell always wc,happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastian Engel told,
Removing the project-local .gradle folder will do it. It will be recreated during the next build and all will be fine again.

Gradle cache located at

On Windows: `%USER_HOME%.gradle/caches`
On Mac/Unix: `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`

You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

on Unix or OS X system.
Refer: [Gradle Build Failed in Android Studio (Cannot read testArtifacts.bin from cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651408/gradle-build-failed-in-android-studio-cannot-read-testartifacts-bin-from-catch)