# Android Gradle Sync Failed to Sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android  Gradle Sync Failed to Sync project:

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/plugins/PluginManagerInternal;
```

[image]

Comment: which version are u using ?:

Comment: Android studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue of gradle cache. I think you need to clear it out. The best solution over SO is here as

> "You can safely delete the whole .gradle folder located under project directory. It'll be recreated every time the tasks are run. The same is for .gradle under home directory. It'll also be recreated as well, but the whole dependencies must be downloaded again - it's quite time-consuming.
>
> As I see in various places over the web gradle for android development
>   is quite slow and people complain about it. No idea what's reason
>   exactly - this is how it works.
>
> I don't think that low performance is because of big folders. Actually
>   they help it to be faster.
>
> there might gradle.properties as well as global gradle scripts located
>   under $HOME/.gradle. In such case special attention must be paid when
>   deleting the content of this directory."

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache) link .
 And please select it as a answer if it helps and let me know.,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I deleted the .gradle and .Android(android studio version)1.5 folders inside c:/users and started Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

There's usually a problem with `gradle cache` when it gets corrupt. I used this [solve gradle sync guide](https://www.tehrir.com/gradle-sync-failed) to fix the error.

TL;DR: find `.gradle` folder and remove its content.