# Getting DexArchiveMergerException when adding Leanback library

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting `DexArchiveMergerException` when adding the `com.android.support:leanback-v17` library to my Gradle dependencies. My `supportLibraryVersion` is `26.0.1`.

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$rootProject.constraintVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.picassoVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:$rootProject.circleimageviewVersion"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:$rootProject.volleyVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$rootProject.exoplayerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$rootProject.exoplayerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$rootProject.exoplayerVersion"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterknifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterknifeVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache

Answer (score 0):

After long time searching, [this](https://asyoulook.com/computers%20&%20internet/android-unable-to-merge-dex/82120) worked for me:

- delete *.gradle* folder
- perform a *Build > Clean* Project.

Hope it's ok for your.