# Android Studio Gradle Sync

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've been getting error messages since I installed `Android Studio` yesterday,

first it was the `CreateProcess error=216`, which I eventually sorted out,

but now I'm getting this

> Gradle sync failed:
>   C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\jars-2\cmhx5eetujk7j30d3nllwxyrlnugzjw\annotations-25.3.3.jar
>   (Access is denied)

I've **cleared cache repeatedly** and **restarted AS** but that isn't helping.

If anyone can help with this. I'm running `AS 2.2.3` on a `Win 7 32-bit` computer.

Comment: Maybe try to erase the cache? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23029580/2102748

Comment: Looks like your jar file isn't accessible. Make sure that you have set environment variables correctly and try again.

Comment: Okay milosmns, I erased the cache and it took me back to the CreateProcess error=216