# Force refresh of archive

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project has a dependency on an `.aar` file located remotely.

`Android Studio` keeps a copy of this file in my `./gradle/caches` directory

When I clean and re-build the project, the file is not refreshed.

How can I force `Android Studio` to reload the archive from the remote location ?

Or is it possible to disable the `gradle` cache for a specific file ?

EDIT: I'd like to force a refresh of a specific file, not of the whole cache => This question is not a duplicate of [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

Comment: I read that already, it takes too long to clear and rebuild the whole cache, hence my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable caching in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` :

```
org.gradle.caching=false
```

Also you can define a task to do that :

```
task('clearDomainCache', type: Delete, group: 'Utilities',
      description: "Deletes any cached artifacts with the domain of com.myCompany in the Gradle or Maven2 cache directories.") doLast {
   def props = project.properties
   def userHome = System.getProperty('user.home')
   def domain = props['domain'] ?: 'com.myCompany'
   def slashyDomain = domain.replaceAll(/\./, '/')
   file("${userHome}/.gradle/cache").eachFile { cacheFile ->
      if (cacheFile.name =~ "^$domain|^resolved-$domain") delete cacheFile.path
      if (cacheFile.name =~ "^*.aar") delete cacheFile.path
   }
   delete "${userHome}/.m2/repository/$slashyDomain"
}
```

Comment: I've added org.gradle.caching=false to my gradle.properties file and when I build, an old version of the archive reappears in my .gradle directory :(

Comment: try remove old cache and `clean` / `rebuild` .... the best way is to using task @matdev

Comment: I've tried using a task, but running it does not delete the classes.jar file contained in my .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/ directory. Also, even with org.gradle.caching=false, the archive file keep on, reappearing in .gradle/caches

Comment: And what about this option ? `android.enableBuildCache=false` @matdev

Comment: I already set this flag to false, but the .gradle/caches keeps getting rebuilt

Comment: The task in your answer @ArashHatami , does not delete the aar file I'd like to delete. Do you know how to force delete aar files ?

Comment: this statement control delete process`if (cacheFile.name =~ "^$domain|^resolved-$domain")` @matdev

Comment: Many thanks ! I managed to clear the cached aar files by adding the line if (cacheFile.name =~ "^*.aar") delete cacheFile.path