# Whenever I change layout or xml file I need to clean and rebuild my project

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm facing a weird problem that is whenever I change a resource file ( layout file or xml file ) I need to clean and build project (rebuilding the project) so that I can see that change if I didn't do this and run the application ( not instance run means that I uninstall the apk and run the application) the changes won't appear.

I suspect that the problem may be from the stack of libraries I use (Dagger2,AndroidDataBinding,RxAndroid) because both Dagger2 and AndroidDataBinding generate files at compile time.

- I tried to disable the instance run but it didn't solve my problem
- I tried to uninstall the old apk and reinstall the newly generated apk with build apk but it also didn't solve it

What do you think causes this problem .. and do you have any solution for it ?

Comment: Is it happening with every project or only this one?

Comment: I know you have a different problem than this other post, but take a look if the solutions help you. :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache

Comment: @Rishav only this project

Comment: @Barns I don't want to clear the cache each time i change xml file

Comment: Nowhere on that link I posted does it says anything about,  clearing the cache each time.