# Failed to resolve: support-fragment error when add google architecture component dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components

I want to use Google architecture components in my app, but after updating android studio to version 3.1.1 when I add `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` dependency into app.gradle file, it will show `Failed to resolve: support-fragment`
My gradle version is 4.4

[image]

This is app gardle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.apptori.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
}
```

Please guid me how to fix it, Thanks

Comment: show your build file

Comment: I copied and pasted your build configuration into a new project and got nothing. Any other things you are doing to your project?

Comment: No, I created a new project and I still have this issue

Comment: tried cleaning and/or clearing caches?

Comment: @Chisko Thank you. After clearing gradle caches the issue fixed.

Comment: I had a similar error and fixed it by [deleting Gradle's cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had a similar error and changing the `repositories` order so that `google()` comes before `jcenter()` fixed it.

I had to change the order for the `repositories` within `buildscript` **and** `allprojects` in the top level `build.gradle` file.

Please see this commit:
https://github.com/kunadawa/ud851-Exercises/commit/9f6720ef4d52c71b206ddaa8477f2cf6e77a66f4

Answer (score 1):

I also had to remove the maven url from the project build.gradle as in:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
          //  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

---

This now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

add these two to   build.gradle -> repositories

```
{
mavenCentral()
google() 
}
```

and add to these are to allprojects

```
allprojects {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
google()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i add this line in build.gradle and fixed bug :
`implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5'`

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me with a project I cloned from github.

I updated my SDK and buildtools and had to double check all the dependencies to match the `buildToolsVersion` and the `compileSdkVersion` from the project.

The error message wasn't very clear when I tried to sync the project, it only gave me a more explicit error when I tried to run and it failed.

`Could not find support-fragment.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2).`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

for a similar issue its solved by changing material implementation from alpha2 version to alpha 7 in the **app build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```