# Flutter Build Crash

Tags: android, flutter

Every time I run `flutter run`  the build always crashes
And brings this out!

> Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice
> graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
> "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone
> x86 arm in debug mode... [Fatal Error]
> kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.pom:2:1: Content is not
> allowed in prolog.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50.
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50.
> > > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.pom
> > > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50.
> > > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.pom
> > > Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       191.0s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.26.0-1.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-1.0.pre at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 63062a6443 (11 days ago), 2020-12-13 23:19:13 +0800
    • Engine revision 4797b06652
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-141.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825507/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-during-gradle-build

Answer (score 0):

Type `flutter doctor -v` into terminal
If there are any errors that appear there, try to fix them first.
If there is no error in the installation, try to get the apk with the code `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. If the error continues, you can write a comment.

Comment: the `flutter doctor -v` seems okay!

Comment: I have posted the `flutter doctor -v`