# EXPO Native app that works fails when running in android

Tags: android, expo, jcenter

I've been working on this for weeks and can't find a resolution.

I have a native app that I've been buildling with expo. IT runs perfectly for the ios simulator.  But, when I try to run it with android, it stalls, showing this message:

[image]

This is a thread I referenced: [Content is not allowed in prolog during Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825507/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-during-gradle-build)

Where they recommend deleting the contents of the shown files.  Of note, I didn't have a build_cache, but I erased the files, and I'm still getting the same error.

IN truth, the error looks more like this:

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
.

WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.

I commented out jcenter() in build.gradle.  IS it anywhere else?  Do you have any other ideas?

Thank you for considering this!

Answer (score 0):

In gradle there is a default cache folder, so you might need to delete it as well.
You can look at the following post for instructions how to do so:
[how to clear gradle cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

In addition, in gradle you may also have a repository definition in the file settings.gradle. try checking that you do not have the jcenter repository referenced there.