# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException while gradle sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Since Monday I am facing an issue related to sun.security.ValidatorException. Before last Monday every thing was working fine.

Exception is :
A problem occurred configuring root project 'CoreApp'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not download sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.2)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.2/sdk-common-26.1.2.jar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.2/sdk-common-26.1.2.jar'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not download sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.2)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.1.2/sdklib-26.1.2.jar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.1.2/sdklib-26.1.2.jar'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   
>   Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

My app level gradle is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2000044
        versionName "4.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.9@aar'
    compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project level gradle is :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. Please help I am not able to development due to this error.

Comment: can you check firewall on your internet connection. it restricts some dependencies to download.

Comment: Yes I have  checked Firewall If I oprn link 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar' in browser than We are able to download jar file without any restriction

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem a while ago, I did the following

1. Make sure you have disabled offline work form Project Settings
2. If you are working on windows just clear the gradle caches ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)) and then sync the project. It should work.

Comment: did not work for me. I have deleted .gradle chache  and invalidat/restrat but same problem

Comment: [try this then](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think its a JDK issue because  I am able to create new project and its working fine. I think its a dependency problem but don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You will probably need to get the certificiate from the site that is failing and import it into your cacerts file. Once you've done that, kill any Gradle daemons and try your build again.

Answer (score 0):

I see this sometimes when I forget to run IntelliJ in admin mode. Running in admin mode has solved this issue for me several times. Not sure why, but hopefully this helps someone else.