# Kill all Gradle Daemons Regardless Version?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-daemon

**Summary**

I would like to know how to kill every single gradle daemon and process running on a machine regardless of the version of gradle or the version of the daemon, but the "--kill" or "--stop" command will only stop those processes that match the same version of gradle.

**Use case**

My CI build box will have several gradle daemons running with different versions (because I'm a good boy that uses the wrapper to execute builds). Occasionally I will find issues with caching or incremental builds, and as a precaution I like to kill the daemons. The same is true for my development boxes, although the conflicts are more often with whichever VCS or IDE I am using.

**What I am looking for**

1. I'm hoping there is a flag or property I am missing that I could
   pass to gradle to do this in a simple one line command, but if it's
   simple enough I would be ok with more.
2. No scripting (looping,
   if-else etc).
3. Killing all java processes is **not** acceptable.

**Helpful links to the gradle docs**

[Disabling the Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon)

[Stopping an existing Daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Under linux you may use pkill:

```bash
pkill -f '.*GradleDaemon.*'
```

Under windows you may use wmic:

```bash
WMIC PROCESS where "Name like 'java%' AND CommandLine like '%GradleDaemon%'" Call Terminate
```

PS. Why "no scripting" when it is probably the easiest solution?

Comment: I basically wanted something that would be really easy for developers on my team to remember and I needed it to be OS agnostic. I can write a script on my own, but I am (or was) hoping for something that was part of gradle (like a "--stop-all" flag). Your solution is also nice, so I could use it in a script that checks for the OS first and then executes one of those two commands, but I'm going to wait a but before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: The windows command doesn't work on my machine, presumably because the CommandLine argument doesn't contain the string, "GradleDaemon".

Answer (score 16):

The gradle daemons did not disappear after 3hrs; this could be since I am running as Linux Guest in VirtualBox.

And hence, the following removes all gradle daemons but it could be "frowned upon" since it might be excessive...

1. ./gradlew --stop   to ensure all daemons are stopped
2. delete all folders/files in .gradle folder in the project
3. delete .gradle folder in /home/username/
   Linu
4. reboot

All daemons are gone. The next build takes a bit longer but worthwhile as do not like seeing 6 stopped daemons everytime a gradle build or even clean is started.

Comment: I think all you need to do is delete `/home/username/.gradle/daemons`

Comment: gradlew --stop worked for me.  Killing Java didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

The `gradle --status` command will show you the process ids for each of the daemons. You can then use your OS to kill those processes.

I'm assuming this is cross-platform functionality, but this is the output on Windows:

```
  PID STATUS   INFO
10276 IDLE     5.4.1
14068 IDLE     5.4.1
```

It's a bit better than playing whack-a-mole with every java.exe process running on your system. Although it would be nice if gradle had a command that could terminate all running gradle daemons built-in.

Comment: `gradle --status` works the same as `--stop` and only lists daemons of the same version as the one you're running.

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar problem and I made this:

1. Go To C:\Users\"Username"\.gradle\daemon
2. There are a Folder for each version of gradle
3. Delete the folder of your actual running version
   Check with --status