# Unable to start Gradle daemon process

Tags: java, gradlew

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\PC-1\.gradle\native
Removing 0 daemon stop events from registry
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: C:\Users\PC-1\.gradle\daemon\4.10.3 Command: C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe -Xmx3g -Dfile.encoding=windows-1254 -Duser.country=TR -Duser.language=tr -Duser.va
riant -cp C:\Users\PC-1\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.3-all\81msde2dx9p4vji0mjgtvxkcb\gradle-4.10.3\lib\gradle-launc
her-4.10.3.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10.3
Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
An attempt to start the daemon took 0.096 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Firstly I downloaded the lquidbounce's source code after I deleted the .gradle
and I posted --info of the code I hope y'all can help me

Comment: Not sure what that last sentence means.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap
```

Not enough free memory for your requested `-Xmx3g`.

1. Do you actually need that much for the build tool itself?
2. Do you have other stuff (especially other Gradle daemons perhaps) you can kill off.
   [Kill all Gradle Daemons Regardless Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189630/kill-all-gradle-daemons-regardless-version)