# Error:failed while loading project Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Tags: java, android

[getting Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8oUP.png)

[Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/RegularFileProperty;'
org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/RegularFileProperty;

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

][2]

Comment: My Android studio version is 4.1.3

Comment: Use following to kill all daemons, then clean project and sync it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794403/5758843