# how to run an existing project of react native

Tags: javascript, android, windows, react-native, npm

I wanted to download and run someone else's project in order to consider its functions. I ran into a number of problems ... that it does not deign to start, and I just don’t know what to do, help, please

https://github.com/sunlight3d/react_native_v0.49/tree/master/61-Realm%20React%20Native%235.Filter%20data%20and%20working%20with%20To-Many%20Relationships/code/tutorialProject

1) copied to the working folder tutorial project

2) opened VS code

3) went into the working folder and clicked open in cmd folder tutorial project

4) then I enter `react-native run-android`
and get fiasco

```
d:\JS\tutorialProject>react-native init tutorialProject
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657 throw err; ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs' at
 Function.Module._resolveFilename
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15) at Function.Module._load
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25) at Module.require
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19) at require
 (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16) at Object.<anonymous>
 (d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cli.js:12:1)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30) at
 Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32) at
 tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12) at
 Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
```

I started googling and found something to do with some dependencies. Using `react-native init MyProject`

5) `react-native init tutorialProject` and getting the tighter right line

I try to start the server through `npm` and then it's funny ...
6) `npm-intall`

```
d:\JS\tutorialProject>npm install npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7:
 core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3
 or at least to actual version of core-js@2. npm WARN deprecated
 connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated npm ERR! path
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native npm ERR! code
 EEXIST npm ERR! Refusing to delete
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native: is outside
 d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\react-native and not a link npm
 ERR! File exists: d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\.bin\react-native
 npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
 C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-16T18_15_13_614Z-debug.log
```

and here I am absolutely don't know. How to run someone else's project?

Comment: I don't think so is meant for questions like this. You may also get better answer using [repository's issue page](https://github.com/sunlight3d/react_native_v0.49/issues)

Answer (score 12):

When you download after you need to install all package in `package.json`

```
npm install --save
```

then you need to start another terminal

```
npm start -- --reset-cache / npm start / react-native start
```

It's for starting your bundler

finally you can run your project

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: can you share u node version node -v and npm -v

Comment: npm 6.9.0
node 11.13.0

Answer (score 0):

From a computer with node install, you navigate a command line to the root of the project folder.

Then you install dependencies:

`npm i`

This installs all the libraries the project needs to build

Then you run the projects build script. This is defined in the projects package.json file. In that projects case, the script is called start. So:

`npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

all dependencies and plugins have configured in `package.json` file. so you need to install:

```
npm install
```

then, you can start

```
react-native run-android
```

or

```
npm run start
```

Comment: when i  write npm install i have a error 
___
path d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules.bin\react-native npm ERR! code EEXIST npm ERR! Refusing to delete d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules.bin\react-native: is outside d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules\react-native and not a link npm ERR! File exists: d:\JS\tutorialProject\node_modules.bin\react-native npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Comment: delete `node_modules` folder and tryagain it will work.... cuz those file already exist there so error..

Comment: use commend react-native/run-android

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a bundle app (android or ios ...)

```
react-native run-android / react-native run-ios
```

else you should run

```
react-native start
```

and then run :

```
react-native run-android (or ios)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer when you compile on windows and android studio

1.Open cmd(as an admin)
2. Npm install
3. Wait for build gradle in Android studio done compiling
4. Run on cmd react-native android-run

Sometimes you may get this error (refer image below)

This is a failure to build because of gradle error. To solve this, you may try to delete the files/folder in the error message and run again react-native android-run.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Actually this is the answer rather than questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm i` or `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

All these answers say to use npm but you might run into issues with global dependencies if you have multiple projects or versions.

It's better if you use npx to have the dependency packages contained in the project folder.

This worked for me but I had to control-c it a few times:

`npx react-native start --reset-cache && npx react-native run-android`

or just:

`npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score -1):

Install Chocolatey
Chocolatey is a popular package manager for Windows. So at first, we need to install it on our system.

To install Chocolaty, Open  **Command Prompt with administrator privileges** and run the command below.

@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8.

npm install –g react-native-cli

[More Detail Follow this](https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-react-native-on-windows-10/)

[image]

**Path in user variable upper section**
[image]

[image]

[image]