# Local stream missing from session object - ConnectyCube Video Chat API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, connectycube

I am initiating a video call with the ConnectyCube `videochat` API. In their [example app](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-reactnative-samples) the session object returned from the code below includes a `localStream` object. I cannot however get this to work - `localStream` is always `null`.

```
const getSession = (calleesIds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sessionType = ConnectyCube.videochat.CallType.VIDEO;
    const additionalOptions = {};
    const session = ConnectyCube.videochat.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType, additionalOptions);
    console.log(session)
    resolve(session);
  })
}
```

When debugging their example app, the session object looks like this:

[image: sessin object]

but mine looks like this:

[image: My session object]

The object then gets passed to the `getUserMedia` function:

```
const getUserMedia = session => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    session.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: { facingMode: 'user' }
    }, function(error, stream) {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(stream);
    });
  });
}
```

However this returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined`.

### Update

Still unable to solve this - it should be possible to figure it out by comparing the functional example app linked to above to my code.

Comment: Still want to put a bounty on this? I can put one on, if you like.

Comment: The problem here was with some very confused dependencies. To fix it I had to delete the gradle cache as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache

Comment: @halfer thanks for the offer - it has now been solved!