# Android React Native app crashes on getUserMedia WebRTC call

Tags: javascript, webrtc, react-native, connectycube

I have been debugging this and no longer have many options, hence the long shot question - I'm using the ConnectyCube WebRTC video calling [package](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-reactnative-samples) for React Native. I have also tried using the `react-native-webrtc` package to stream video from my Android device.

When using both packages my app crashes without any logs or errors when I call the getUserMedia method. I have to build the app again to use it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647793/local-stream-missing-from-session-object-connectycube-video-chat-api) is a previous post of mine that describes earlier problems I was having - however if you download and build ConnectyCubes app from the above link, their app works - I can't figure out why mine doesn't.

So my question is, is is there anything I should be checking for relating to the `getUserMedia` call in React Native that might be stopping it working?

I'm using:

```
RN v0.59.9 
gradle wrapper 5.4.1 
classpath(“com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1”)
buildToolsVersion = “28.0.3”
compileSdkVersion = 28
```

I have reached out to support but have no fix yet.

Strangely, I'm unable to log the `session` parameter at certain points in the function.

```js
const getUserMedia = session => {
  console.log(session); // logs here 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(session); // but not here
    session.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: { facingMode: 'user' }
    }, function (error, stream) {
      console.log(error, stream) // or here
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(stream);
    });
  });
}
```

#Update#
The issue with the function above might be that for some reason the crash happens before the console can print anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by deleting the gradle cache and running npm i as described here:

[How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)