# .gradle folder increases every run flutter debug

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

please your advice, i have trouble each time running flutter debug.

Every time I run or debug, the .gradle folder will be created as shown below.

Well, the problem is, the folder always increases in size every time I debug. Of course this is a problem as I experienced, suddenly my hard drive is full, and after I check it turns out that the .gradle folder reaches 30GB in size, and when I try to run debug again the size continues to increase ..

Are there any settings for this problem ??

Please advise.
sorry for my bad english.
[image: []

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

Comment: @Albert221, but why the .gradle folder is too big every run debug ? could you explain to me ?