# "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The following error occurs when I tried to build the app:

> C:/Users/Lenovo/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/32f0bb3e96b47cf79ece6482359b6ad2/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16

[image: screenshot]

Is it about updating the module? Then how to update it?

Comment: Can you show up your app and project build.gradle

Comment: In my case problem occurs with the Jetpack DataStore library. I removed it and rebuild. the problem removed, but don't able to know why this happens.!!!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

For someone who is still looking for answer to this, here is the working solution for this problem. In your project level open `build.gradle` file, increase the
`ext.kotlin_version` from whatever current version that you have like `1.5.0`, to the latest stable version `1.6.0` (Whatever is latest at that time). Thanks

You can get latest version from here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

Comment: It does work, but could you please tell me how it works.

Comment: From what I think, Sometimes, Android Studio stops supporting Kotlin Older versions, especially when your android studio is up to date. This is just my thinking, I also don't know the exact reason. But this solution works for sure everytime.

Comment: In My case, this problem arose, when I updated some plugins in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes changing the version of `gradle-6.7.1` to `gradle-6.9` in `gradle-wraper-properties` file and also changing the `ext.kotlin-version = '1.4.32'` resolve the issue.

Comment: Setting to `1.5.31` in a `flutter@2.5.2` project fixed it for me.

Comment: With `Kotlin v1.6.0`, if you are using `Moshi` library you need to update it to `v1.13.0`. Also with `Moshi v1.13.0`, you need to update `Gradle` and `AGP` to `v7.+` or disable Jetifier for `Moshi` library as a workaround! 
See this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184622491

Comment: ```./gradlew cleanBuildCache```

Comment: This works if you use `kotlin_version` property somewhere for version

Comment: in my case latest version 1.6.10 is not work, but 1.6.0 is works fine.

Comment: This dependencies type in flutter is a mood killer

Comment: This did not solve my problem. What worked for me was - I got this error, when I was adding another library released later than the kotlin library I was using. So when I replaced the added library with a version older than the kotlin version, my problem was resolved. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have this error: Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.2. What should I do?

Comment: also I have `dependencies { classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"`, do I need change it to 1.6.0?

Comment: @AliRaza In my case (an Android Studio React Native project) the variable turned out to be called `kotlinVersion`, not `kotlin_version`

Comment: This solution does not work with React Native. Some 3rd party libraries are not able to use the latest Kotlin, therefore, the app does not build or crashes on open

Answer (score 68):

Happened to me when updating from Kotlin `1.4.30` to `1.5.0`. Seems to be some sort of `Gradle` caching issue. I was able to resolve it by updating `Gradle` from `6.7.1` to `6.9` (or any other version).

Just go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change this line from

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip

Comment: Don't do this. Just follow Ali Raza's answer.

Comment: @KishanSolanki could you please explain why? Ali Raza's answer didn't help me!

Comment: Ali's answer didn't work for me either error remained the same

Comment: Many answers and comments are very specific to versions that are now outdated. A more generic answer would have been more helpful.

Comment: I just added a new version in android/build.gradle file. In fact, if you get kotlin version error, it will take you to kotlin website, you can copy the version from there and put in android/build.gradle file. But sometimes you may need to get correct version from     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    } If you hover on it, it will tell you the correct one and put it there

Comment: not working with this solution.

Answer (score 46):

I was facing same issue in IntelliJ IDEA Version: Ultimate 2019.3

Issue occurred when I changed jar version multiple times and click on debug button to run the application.

Issue fixed when i used below steps:

Open IntelliJ >> Build >> Rebuild Project.

After that I run the application again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I updated kotlin versions to latest and it helped me.

Here

[image]

And fixed yellow prompt by Android Studio from this
`implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"` to this
`implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0"`

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: in which files ?

Answer (score 19):

In my case, I don't have a `buildScript` block or `ext.kotlin_version` in my `ProjectRoot/build.gradle`. Instead, there is a `plugins` block which describe my kotlin version.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}
```

Change `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` to `1.7.10`, like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

This finally get worked, hope to help someone.

Answer (score 10):

I had to update the Kotlin Gradle plugin to match Kotlin standard library. In `{project}/build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:{kotlin version}"
    }
}
```

I also removed callout to dependency on standard library as that is now baked into Gradle based on my dependencies, though this is less directly related.
Delete this line in `{project}/{app module}/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:{kotlin version}"
    ...
}
```

Reference: [Exception Error blog post](https://exerror.com/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1-5-1-expected-version-is-1-1-15/)

Answer (score 8):

In my case Problem occurs when I upgrade `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1` to `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0`

In release notes of this library mentioned that

**Note: Core and Core-ktx Version 1.5.0** and above versions will only compile against the Android 11 SDK.**

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#core_and_core-ktx_version_150_2

Solution: downgrade your library below to **1.5.0** and sync. if this is the case then the error will be gone.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me today when I added a new project to an existing big project with latest Android Studio, but I could not find the above-mentioned `ext.kotlin_version` anywhere to fix it. Anyway, after comparing the build.gradle file with the one from a new standalone project that works fine, I found out that changing `1.6.0` in here:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    ...
}
```

to `1.3.2` fixes the issue:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Uncleared Gradle cache could also be an issue. I faced this same issue and resolved it by deleting `.gradle/caches` directory in the root folder.

Steps:

- Delete `caches` directory in the location, `[RootFolder]/.gradle/caches`
- Do Invalidate Caches And Restart
- Rebuild project

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23029580/10506244

Comment: This did not work for me. After running it, I got another message about cache files no longer existing causing me to have to kill all running gradle instances with `pkill -f gradle`. After that, it went back to the original error message that the OP described.

Answer (score 6):

Go project build.gradle and update "ext.kotlin_version = 1.5.0"

Answer (score 5):

First, we need to know where the conflict comes from.

The binary version 1.5.1 isn't the version of kotlin-stdlib used which can be known by examining the dependency tree. In my case, I was using [androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/core/core-ktx/1.6.0) which depends on org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10

The expected version depends on the version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin` used in `build.gradle` project file.

So in my case, there was incompatibility between `androidx.core:core-ktx` and `kotlin-gradle-plugin` version. To resolve the conflict, I had two options. Either upgrade KGP or downgrade ktx.

In build.gradle (Project)

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'     // not compatible with ktx:1.6.0
//  ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31' // upgrading KGP fixes the issue
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

In build.gradle (Module)

```
//  implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0" // downgrading ktx fixes the issue
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"     // not compatible with kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

The rule here is to choose a ktx version whose release date is close to the release date of KGP. Links of both can be found below.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 5):

The issue is happening for RN since 4th Nov 2022, Please refer below link for resolution. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because they become invalid when the link goes stale. Please copy the relevant portions over from the link (keeping it as additional reference).

Answer (score 4):

If anyone face this issue in future kindly check the following `versions` of `dependencies` and `classpath`

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
```

> Esure that the `gradle-wrapper.properties` has the compitable
> distribution url with your kotlin version

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-bin.zip

**App level `build.gradle` check**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3'
```

**Note: Check these dependencies it might be causing the issue, In my case `coroutines-android` was using 1.6.0-RC2 which is very latest version of coroutine then I checked the github releases and got the right version for my project gradle configuration**

You can check the `kotlinx-coroutines-android` version from github releases section

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases

You can also check the `core-ktx` version from developer.android.com

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

Answer (score 4):

Inside `android/build.gradle` you need to change, or add, if you don't have:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.1"
}
```

Comment: > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.

Answer (score 3):

For library builders only. **If you are creating a library using a newer version of Kotlin (eg. 1.8.10) and you want the library to work in projects with older versions of Kotlin (eg. 1.5.0)** you need to set `languageVersion` and `apiVersion`:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        languageVersion = '1.4'
        apiVersion = '1.4'
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the lower the version the fewer new Kotlin features you would be able to use in the source code of the library.

Comment: `could not find method compileKotlin() for arguments`

Comment: Same here: `Could not find method compileKotlin()` — why is not one ever telling you where precisely the option goes? Please do add all the parents sections!

Comment: you can put it in address android>app in 
android{
 ....
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        languageVersion = '1.4'
        apiVersion = '1.4'
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Recently my Jenkins build was failing with similar lines of error messages. And tried below to mitigate the issue:

**Possible Reasons:**

1. Offline work mode is ON in the Gradle settings options which failing some dependencies while compilation
2. Updated Android Studio stop supporting older Kotlin version. (very less likely)
3. Incompatible Gradle distribution version wrt Gradle plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle)
4. Gradle caching issue
5. From the error statement it seems the module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. For example you have added some sdk dependency in your project which was compiled with different (incompatible) kotlin version than your app is using.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Offline work mode should be turned OFF in the Gradle settings options,
2. Restart the Kotlin plugin and restart the Android Studio
3. Remove/upgrade the newly added sdk dependency from your project
4. Validate if the Gradle distribution version is compatible with Android grade plugin [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
5. Change the “distributionUrl” url according to latest version (or higher version) in gradle-wrapper.properties
   **Command Line (better way)**: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version X.Y.Z'.

   **Manual:** change the distributionUrl property in the Wrapper’s gradle-wrapper.properties file.

   find the latest version of Gradle that is going to use in gradle-wrapper.properties from [here](https://services.gradle.org/versions/current)
6. Upgrade the Kotlin version: The ext.kotlin.version from whatever version you have, to '1.4.32' or whatever the latest version is available [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

Please note there could be many possible reason and so that the solution. In My case the combination of solution#5 & 6 worked well.

Comment: Yup, #5 & 6 for me as well

Answer (score 2):

After putting off dealing with this for almost a year, the solution was very easy to implement after finding.

I had to replace the deprecated jcenter() with mavenCentral() in my build.gradle file in the "repositories" section.

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle file, increase the ext.kotlin_version to  1.6.0

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

you have juste rebuild your project:

1. Open IntelliJ IDE
2. Build
3. Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to update `Android Studio` to `4.2.2`. Update `gradle` to `7.0`. As well as perform the `kotlin` migration(might not have had anything to do with it). And lastly updated my `ext.kotlin`_version to `1.5.20`. After all of that I invalidated caches and restarted `Android studio`.

Answer (score 1):

For me updating the kotlin plugin, kotlin version and distribution url worked
[image: Kotlin Plugin]

```
kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

AND

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday. The solution is to change the kotlin version in build.gradle to 1.5.0 and change the Gradle version in the project structure to 6.9.

```
ext.kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For someone who is still looking for answer to this, here is the working solution for this problem. In your project level open build.gradle file, increase the ext.kotlin_version from whatever current version that you have like 1.3.61, to the  version 1.4.0 (Whatever is latest at that time). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in my case flutter project and Android studio IDE, kotlin version and gradle version was updated before.

`file > Invaladate caches` was worked like charm.

to manually delete the cache, you may try:

deleting from `C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches`

Answer (score 1):

For react native following solution works

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    // ...
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
+       exclusiveContent {
+           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
+           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
+           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
+           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
+           filter {
+               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
+           }
+           forRepository {
+               maven {
+                   // NOTE: if you are in a monorepo, you may have "$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
+                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
+               }
+           }
+       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated everything to the latest version. And the latest mentioned by the android studio itself.

e.g

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0-alpha04"
    }
```

And

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours testing different versions of Kotlin being my project **NOT A KOTLIN PROJECT** this solution solved my life:

Go to Intellij and disable the Kotlin plugin. Then compile everything again.

Comment: For me this crashed AndroidStudio and it would not start anymore. I had to manually fix the disabled_plugins.txt to make it work again.

Comment: Oh I am sorry to hear that!

Comment: Android studio stopped opening

Comment: On IntelliJ and not using or care about kotlin at all, disabling kotlin puglin actually works! This gives me a hint that the issue might be coming from intellij plugin that use kotlin.

Comment: Android studio gives error "Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch."

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue why this happens is because of incompatibility with the kotlin compiler version and the gradle plugin version

I spawned up a new Android project in Chipmunk and I find that the kotlin_version variable under the `ext` block is not there and `build.gradle` will hardcode the kotlin version

So change your `build.gradle` (global) like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0-beta02'
        kotlin_version = '1.6.21'// This might be missing, you can add it
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0"
    


// Do not hardcode this version, instead make it rely on the global variable you declared on top

//No
//classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20"
//Yes
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why simply upgrading the Kotlin version works: At least one of your dependencies was compiled against a version of Kotlin that is not backward compatible with the Kotlin version you are compiling your app or lib against.

Alternatively, you can find out which dependency it is and downgrade it. However, this can be limiting, so upgrade Kotlin versions if you can.

Remember the pain, and if you ever write a Kotlin library for others to use, consider being conservative in the Kotlin version you compile against, and list that version in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new version in android/build.gradle file. In fact, if you get kotlin version error, it will take you to kotlin website, you can copy the version from there and put in android/build.gradle file. But sometimes you may need to get correct version from

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

If you hover on it, it will tell you the correct one and put it there
More here https://youtu.be/WTEPNOQdpB0

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the conflict comes from the saved android studio project settings. Try to sync you project with Gradle files [android studio shortcut.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kybAO.png)

from: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

This will rebuild the and download all the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the gradle plugin to the latest version. Android Studio v3.0+ will prompt to update gradle if there is an update available.

For a Flutter project, open the Android application in Android Studio and upgrade gradle as mentioned above.

Comment: Upgrading Gradle is a mayor hassle. Most likely nothing will compile any more and I need a week or so to get everything to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while I ran the command `react-native run-android` after a few weeks to run my project. After running the command I noticed that `react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar` is being downloaded. After digging around on internet I came across this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204) on github and [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204#issuecomment-1304105112) which stated the cause of the problem. as the comment states:

> - typical react-native publish does not publish to maven central.
> - this RC was published to maven central and has a higher version than local
> - typical react-native build.gradle thus pulls the new (unwanted) RC version from maven central

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) was the solution to the problem, what is says is that people at `react-native` have prepared patch fixes to which you can update your current version of `react-native`, to fix the problem. I was using `react-native` version `0.68.2` and I updated to the patch version of `0.68.5` as the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) stated and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced this problem
this is happened to me due to latest cotourine version from:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC")
```

to:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
```

So please check maven repository & get downgraded version.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happend even in maven projects, if there is kotlin arifacts somewhere in dependencies. Just disable kotlin and it shall work. Intellij developers should have focused on fixing their core bugs before pushing their wannabe 'platform' into public domain.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers refer to the deprecated (imperative) style of the gradle build files, I try to give an answer that applies to the current situation (as of March 2024, after migrating to the [declarative style](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)), having spent almost a day fixing the build files of our mobile app.

First some general hints:

- In flutter these errors appear when you run either `flutter build apk` or `flutter build appbundle`, but they are gone (due to caching some intermediate artifacts) when you invoke the command subsequently. You have to invoke `flutter clean` to get them back
- Android Studio Iguana has an [AGP Upgrade assistant](https://developer.android.com/build/agp-upgrade-assistant) that may work automatically in some situations, but at least it delivers som hints on why and how to fix things
- If you have a flutter project, you may open the android part either using a menu entry or using the file system if the menu entry doesn't show up, giving you some more non-flutter functionality or easier access to gradle sync

The error imo is the result of a mismatch of the android gradle plugin and the kotlin standard lib. Now, the current android gradle plugin versions (7.x/8.x for some x) ***do not need to have an explicit dependency on the kotlin standard lib any more***, as they automatically add a matching one. Therefore you can remove the line `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"` (or similar - version suffixes don't solve the problem) from dependencies section in `android/app/build.gradle`.

When you create a new project using flutter (v 3.19.4, as of now) by invoking `flutter create myproject`, it creates an empty dependencies section in the app module build file (android/app/build.gradle). After migration from the imperative build style, it is recommended to have this plugins section in `android/settings.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false
}
```

with values for `agpVersion` and `kotlinVersion` set to `7.3.0`and `1.7.10` respectively - current values as of now are `8.3.1` and `1.9.23` (tested with java 17).

Answer (score -1):

I've tried all the listed answers, none of them worked with the latest react native (0.70.6).

My solution was using android studio to run app on AVD or device first and make sure it installs all the required sdks or libraries. I am surprised since I went through the instructions before to bootstrap RN.

For me, it took some time to initial run on device or AVD.
after doing so, running the app from cli worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Create new project again helped for me :|
And if you need to fix another project you may try copy **android/build.gradle** and **android/app/build.gradle** from new flutter project template to an other project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Finally, the working solution is that we need to upgrade your kotlin version from your project build.gradle file.