# IntelliJ Error:Kotlin: Module was compiled

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have used IntelliJ IDE just for **Spring Boot** project. Strong NOTE that I have **not used any Kotlin project.** But, today, I have an error below. Any professional person. Please, HELP to solve this issue! Thanks,
*Error:Kotlin: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.13.*

Comment: Do answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version help?

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the same problem, and my solution was:

If you do not use Kotlin in your project, you can solve the problem by turning off the IntelliJ IDE plugin.The operation is as follows：

idea menu：File>Setting>Plugins

[Operation flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TZU4.png)

Comment: I do not have this plugin installed

Answer (score 6):

According to solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093698/13248380

Try going to *Build* menu and choose *Rebuild project*.