# i am getting an error whn i a run my code in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

C:/Users/Vansh Aggarwal/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0d5ca0c77f4abe6fea85b2569e7da0c8/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version)