# How to change ABI version of my compiler?

Tags: android-studio, abi

I am about to use external libraries but they does not work, when i look at them i found this

```
    // This class file was compiled with different version of Kotlin compiler and can't be decompiled.
//
// Current compiler ABI version is 1.1.16
// File ABI version is 1.5.1
```

so i was wondering how to update my compiler Abi version
and also, should i be worried about, may some other external libraries  conflict with this? It is posible to manage different compiler ABI version?

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin compiler should provide for specifying source and target version compatibility.

- **Source** version means what features of the Kotlin language are supported. Should be https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#language-version-version
- **Target** version defines what version the resulting JVM bytecode is going to be. I think this is the right switch: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#jvm-target-version.  When talking about ABI version this is what matters. Note that still you may want to change the source version if an older target version does not support new language features.

Comment: Hi Tony, i am kind new on this topic of compilers, i really cant understand to much, what code should i use to change my Current compilar Abi version?

Comment: Rodrigo, can you go through this previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version. There are a number of better answers than mine. I am not a Kotlin but a Java developer myself. Specifically the cannot-decompile error points to your IDE using an older Kotlin version than what the library was compiled with - can you update your IDE?

Comment: thats is the part that i missing, because i go to the Settings-> kotlin compiler an it says  LanguageVersion (Latest stable 1.3) ////ApiVersion (Latest stable 1.3)//// Target JVM Version (1.6)////    I was expecting to find something like ABI CompilerVersion (1.1.16) Thats why i dont know where to update it

Comment: Can you try switching to Kotlin up to 1.5 and maybe JVM to 1.8.

Comment: there i did it, but no succed :/