# Android studio when i am trying to run a simple app it is not runnig

Tags: android

i have uninstall app made in kotlin in android studio virtual device nexus 6, and when i try to build the gradle again , it is showing this error.Help me fix this.

e: C:/Users/acer/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3f5d451ee838e9d174f4df0a62e3601f/jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You Can update your **kotlin** version. By opening **build.gradle** file in your application. Please lookout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816693/11560810) it will help you.

Comment: Thanks bro, the new artic fox update has comed in stable version...now it's working, thanks

Comment: @AjayRaut if you accept answer, it will great for other user. Who are looking for same issue.