# Module Error "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am writing a kotlin library for our project. When finished i built an .aar file and sent it to the team. But they have an error as `"Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"` (**core-ktx version of the library was 1.3.2 and kotlin-gradle-plugin version was 1.5.0 at that time**).

I researched about it and found this thread.
["Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version)

I tried given solutions here but none of this worked so far. Whenever i go below version 1.5 of kotlin-gradle-plugin, i see errors like `Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.4, which is older than the API version 1.5?`

I am sharing gradle files here.

build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(:app) :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.neco.myDemoProject"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation project(path: ':myLibrary')
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle(:myLibrary) :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

And here are the versions of dependencies of our project that i need to implement the library to (they are in a text file so i'm copying from there):

```
minSdkVersion: 21
targetSdkVersion: 30
compileSdkVersion: 30

appCompatVersion: "1.0.0"
gradleVersion : "3.3.0"
kotlinVersion: "1.3.60"
coreKtxVersion: "1.0.2"
```

Any suggestions about what to do?

Comment: I had similar problems recently. I updated the `Room` library to `2.4.0-rc01` and as a result, I had to update the `Kotlin` to `1.6.0`. So maybe you need to update the Kotlin in your main project configs. Also because of the experience I had today about generating output files, I highly recommend invalidating Android Studio caches including `build` folder inside `app` module of your main project.

Comment: @YUSMLE I solved my problem downgrading the versions of my library dependencies to the versions of the target application since i have no control over the target application. But if i did, your solution could do good also.  thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3):

Updating this in build.gradle works for me
(in root-level build.gradle  not in app/build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a library using a newer version of Kotlin (eg. 1.8.10) and you want the library to work in projects with older versions of Kotlin (eg. 1.5.0) you need to set `languageVersion` and `apiVersion`:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        languageVersion = '1.4'
        apiVersion = '1.4'
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the lower the version the fewer new Kotlin features you would be able to use in the source code of the library.