# Module was compiled with an incom patible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

My app compiles, but after looking into a few related questions like ([Module Error "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592005/module-error-module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-bi)) How do we actually resolve these issues? My kotlin version is set to:

```
 ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
```

Gradle is:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

Specifically I'm concerned about these packages:

```
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/fluttertoast/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/fluttertoast_release.kotlin_module: Modul
e was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/package_info_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled wit
h an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/audioplayers/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/audioplayers_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incom
patible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/sensors_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/sensors_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incom
patible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/share_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/share_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompati
ble version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/location/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/location_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible
version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
```

Full Error Log:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1645]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\mywindowsusername\Documents\GitHub\myprojectname-prod-flutter-app>flutter build apk --split-per-abi
 Building with sound null safety 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.1.14\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFi
rebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.3.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobInt
entService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutternativeimage\FlutterNat
iveImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sound-9.2.12\android\src\main\java\com\dooboolab\fluttersound\FlutterSound.java uses
 or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or override
s a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_thumbnail-0.5.0\android\src\main\java\xyz\justsoft\video_thumbnail\VideoThumbnailPlugin.java uses unc
hecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\mywindowsusername\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.robolectric\shadows-framework\4.3.1\da048a93951f4d9e46519749c53b0f868dfdf42
5\shadows-framework-4.3.1.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will t
ry to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/test/runner/lifecycle/Stage'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'
WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\mywindowsusername\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.robolectric\shadows-framework\4.3\150103d5732c432906f6130b734e7452855dd67b\
shadows-framework-4.3.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try t
o rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/test/runner/lifecycle/Stage'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/525f5a7fa6d7790a571c07dd24214ed2dda352fe/kotlin-stdlib-jdk
7-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk
8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.31/6628d61d0f5603568e72d2d5915d2c034b4f1c55/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.j
ar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.31/43331609c7de811fed085e0dfd150874b157c32/kotlin-stdlib-co
mmon-1.5.31.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.21/568c1b78a8e17a4f35b31f0a74e2916095ed74c2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk
7-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.21/11ef67f1900634fd951bad28c53ec957fabbe5b8/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.21.j
ar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.21/5e5b55c26dbc80372a920aef60eb774b714559b8/kotlin-stdlib-c
ommon-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.j
ar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-co
mmon-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk
7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/video_compress/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/video_compress_release.kotlin_module: M
odule was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.21/568c1b78a8e17a4f35b31f0a74e2916095ed74c2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
-1.6.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0
, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.21/11ef67f1900634fd951bad28c53ec957fabbe5b8/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.21.ja
r!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected vers
ion is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.21/5e5b55c26dbc80372a920aef60eb774b714559b8/kotlin-stdlib-co
mmon-1.6.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is
 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.ja
r!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected vers
ion is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-com
mon-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is
1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/google_api_headers/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/google_api_headers_release.kotlin_m
odule: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0
, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/fluttertoast/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/fluttertoast_release.kotlin_module: Modul
e was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/package_info_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled wit
h an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/audioplayers/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/audioplayers_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incom
patible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/sensors_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/sensors_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incom
patible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/share_plus/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/share_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompati
ble version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
e: C:/Users/mywindowsusername/Documents/GitHub/myprojectname-prod-flutter-app/build/location/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/META-INF/location_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible
version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          279.5s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (53.9MB).

C:\Users\mywindowsusername\Documents\GitHub\myprojectname-prod-flutter-app>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750321/react-native-screenscompiledebugkotlin-failed