# I am having an issue to run the app in android studio firebase

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, android-studio

> e: /.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d1c1313a2ba094a1260853f4b41ce789/transformed/firebase-auth-22.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.firebase-auth-api_firebase-auth-api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

this the error I don't know what to do tried changing auth version yet same error

I could use a hand in solving this

Comment: Did you try lime's solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be a lot like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version).

The solution is to find and open `build.gradle` file within your project directory and change the `ext.kotlin_version` from whatever version is stated, in your instance it seems it may be `1.9.0`, to the expected version of `1.7.1`