# React Native compilekotlin Failed

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle

I have started learning React Native and want to develop an Android application. I run the following command:

```
npm start
```

I get the following error:
`gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED`

```
e: /Users/ajayshah/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.5-bin/65e7hbml0egfnf6zl3orijbw4/gradle-8.5/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/ajayshah/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.5-bin/65e7hbml0egfnf6zl3orijbw4/gradle-8.5/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/ajayshah/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.5-bin/65e7hbml0egfnf6zl3orijbw4/gradle-8.5/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/ajayshah/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (57, 42): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/ajayshah/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.5-bin/65e7hbml0egfnf6zl3orijbw4/gradle-8.5/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.20.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: /Users/ajayshah/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactExtension.kt: (57, 42): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
```

The above continues for various Kotlin classes but the error is similar in nature in that it mentions "The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1." in each line of error.
I understand a bit about Gradle and updated it to the latest 8.5 version in gradle-wrapper.properties. But the above error from what I understand is that it is expecting 1.7.1 but got 1.9.0. I want to learn how to upgrade this Kotlin to 1.9.0 as well.

I changed the build.gradle (project level) to add a dependency
`classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0")`

But this has no impact. Is there some other place I should be making a change? I am unsure how to proceed. This is my first React Native project and did adequate research before putting this question here.

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version

Comment: nope. I tried this too :)

Comment: I resolved this by going to android folder and using gradlew clean in cli. thank you.