# How to understand kotlin gradle version mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am upgrading android code to a new sdk then got below error:

```
.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.21/11ef67f1900634fd951bad28c53ec957fabbe5b8/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.21.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
```

But my kotlin is `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'` and `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'`

Why the error version mismatch is `The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.`

What's correct version should I use from this logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version)

Comment: Upgrade your Kotlin version to 1.7.20 and use "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0" , It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#gradle-java-toolchains-support) information from kotlin website

We need keep the KGP/AGP/Gradle match below table:

| KGP | Gradle | AGP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.9.20 | 6.8.3–8.1.1 | 4.2.2–7.4.0 |
| 1.9.0–1.9.10 | 6.8.3–7.6.0 | 4.2.2–7.4.0 |
| 1.8.20–1.8.22 | 6.8.3–7.6.0 | 4.1.3–7.4.0 |
| 1.8.0–1.8.11 | 6.8.3–7.3.3 | 4.1.3–7.2.1 |
| 1.7.20–1.7.22 | 6.7.1–7.1.1 | 3.6.4–7.0.4 |
| 1.7.0–1.7.10 | 6.7.1–7.0.2 | 3.4.3–7.0.2 |
| 1.6.20–1.6.21 | 6.1.1–7.0.2 | 3.4.3–7.0.2 |

And add below config to project build.gradle to the same java version, this example use java8 for both:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```