# React Native TextInput closes automatically when opened on android

Tags: react-native

I switched laptops and cloned the repository of my project, did a quick yarn install and looks like it was a big difference from the one on the main branch but I didn't bother since maybe it's just because of different Node versions.

Now every time I click on one TextInput the keyboard opens and closes immediately only on android. I attached a quick recording here. Tried some solutions and it looks like switching android:windowSoftInputMode from adjustResize to adjustPan in AndroidManifest.xml fixes the problem with the closing but I'm not really happy with the behaviour of the keyboard in the app when it's set to adjustPan. Maybe this issue starting happening a while ago but I just saw it now.

Here is just an input centered inside a simple View.
https://gfycat.com/ordinaryquestionabledinosaur

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: maybe try to add a snack containing your problem for a better vision, coz this might be related to your code

Comment: I am also started facing this issue today morning, have you found any solution @Cristain ?

Comment: @AshishGuleria Yes, the answer I accepted solved my issue.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Was facing a similar issue, turned out that the react-native-screens library was causing the problem. Try setting the version to "~3.10.2". Worked out for me.

Comment: Lost my half day on this. Thanks.

Comment: it's giving an error that ./fabric is not found in react-native-screens

Comment: Worked like a charm....don't forget to add the '~'.

Comment: This was not working for me before with npm
But with yarn it worked now for some different project.

Comment: make sure to stop your server and re run it to see the changes. a simple server refresh may not be enough. also consider clearing the gradle cache which you can do like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache

Comment: At the latest version of `react-native-screens` was getting the same issue. On the exact version `~3.10.2` of `react-native-screens`, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 16):

Change the line in AndroidManifest.xml

**Old line**
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

**New line**
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: it worked for me but can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 3):

Change the line in AndroidManifest.xml works for me, I did the update but that does not works

Change the config to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Scroll down for the solution

### Explanation

Okay, so, its been a while since this issue was active, and honestly I find the answers here to be kind of half baked, I have a solution that fixes this problem regardless of `react-native-screens`, but the explanation is quite long, so bear with me here.

The solutions suggesting to upgrade the `react-native-screens` lib are no longer relevant, I am currently running two projects using `react-native-screens@3.20` and both these projects are experiencing the same broken behavior, expect it only happens in `FlatList`s with inputs that are positioned on the lower part of the screen.
So the Upper to middle inputs work fine, but all the inputs that would be placed under the keyboard once it opens, cause the above mentioned weird behavior.
The solutions that suggest to change the `windowSoftInputMode` to `"stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`, i.e: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`.
Fail to mention that this changes the behavior of how the screen resize works entirely, and disallow users to scroll beyond the initially clicked `TextInput`, so if u have a list with multiple text fields, this solution isn't gonna work for you (It didn't for me and my use case).

The solution I'm suggesting is similar to `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan` expect it uses `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` instead. In essence, what this will do, is tell android to do nothing when the `windowSoftInput` (i.e: the software keyboard) opens up. essentially eliminating the automatic layout adjustments. Which achieves two important things:

1. It aligns the resizes behavior (or lack there of) to the behavior of iOS, which is that the view layout stays the same, under the keyboard.
2. Allows us to do our own custom logic, which can now be the same for both iOS and Android, because as mentioned in `1.`, both platforms should now behave the same when the keyboard opens up.

The solution itself, will be to listen to keyboard height changes (open/close) events, and to adjust a padding to the wrapping `View` container, so it essentially "dodges" the keyboard, leaving the scrollview/listView/flatlist/etc (if present) above the keyboard, making it look seamless. This however, requires that we know the size of the view that needs to be padded, so we can extract the diff that needs to be padded (in case the View in question isn't the last element on the screen; incase you have bottom action buttons for example).
All of this can then be packed in a newly composed `View`, we will called it `KeyboardPaddedView` (not to confuse with the built-in `KeyboardAvoidingView`, which I find to be garbage btw). This view will contain all the logic, and can then just be used instead of the original View, which wraps the Flatlist/ScrollView etc.

So again, summed up:

1. Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`
2. Listen to keyboard hight changes
3. Measure the View and its location to determine the needed diff/padding from the keyboard.
4. Wrap everything inside the Measured view for reusability

### The solution

```xml
<!-- 1. Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` -->
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
...
<activity
          ...
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
          ...
>
...

</activity>
```

```js
// keyboard.hks.ts

// 2. Listen to keyboard hight changes (written in typescript)

// Keyboard event hook
export const useOnKeyboardEvent = (
  eventName: KeyboardEventName,
  onEvent: (event: KeyboardEvent) => void,
) => {
  const cb = useCallback((event: KeyboardEvent) => onEvent(event), [onEvent]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = Keyboard.addListener(eventName, cb);
    return () => listener.remove();
  }, [eventName, cb]);
};



type OnUpdateCB = (newHeight: number) => void;
// hook to calculate and set keyboard height
export const useOnKeyboardHeightUpdate = (onUpdate: OnUpdateCB) => {
  const keyboardOpenEvent = useMemo(
    () => (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillShow' : 'keyboardDidShow'),
    [],
  );
  const keyboardCloseEvent = useMemo(
    () => (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillHide' : 'keyboardDidHide'),
    [],
  );

  const cb = useCallback((height: number) => onUpdate(height), [onUpdate]);
  useOnKeyboardEvent(keyboardOpenEvent, (event) =>
    cb(event.endCoordinates.height),
  );
  useOnKeyboardEvent(keyboardCloseEvent, () => cb(0));
};
```

```js
// measures.hks.ts
// 3. Measure the View and its location to determine the needed diff/padding from the keyboard.


// hook to Measure a view's layout inside the container its in,
// in relation to the window, i.e its global/absolute position on screen

export const useWindowMeasuredViewRef = (): [
  MutableRefObject<View | undefined>,
  LayoutRectangle,
  (el: View) => void,
] => {
  const viewRef = useRef<View>();
  const [layoutRect, setLayoutRect] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 });
  const callbackSetter = useCallback(async (el: View) => {
    async function nextFrameAsync() {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
        requestAnimationFrame(() => resolve()),
      );
    }
    // set viewRef element
    viewRef.current = el;
    // view measurements will only be available on the next frame, so we simply await the next frame,
    // so we can correctly measure the view and its layout
    await nextFrameAsync();
    viewRef.current?.measureInWindow(
      (x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) => {
        setLayoutRect({
          x,
          y,
          height,
          width,
        });
      },
    );
  }, []);

  return [viewRef, layoutRect, callbackSetter];
};


// Using the measured view
// get needed bottom padding for keyboard height to offset FlatList component using bottom padding
// helps to get the view above the keyboard correctly, regardless of any view beneath it
export function useKeyboardPaddedHeightForView(): [number, (el: View) => void] {
  const [_viewRef, layout, viewRefSetter] = useWindowMeasuredViewRef();
  const windowDimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  const [keyboardHeight, _setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);
  const diff = useMemo(
    () => windowDimensions.height - layout.height - Math.floor(layout.y),
    [windowDimensions.height, layout],
  );
  const setKeyboardHeight = useCallback(
    (height: number) => {
        _setKeyboardHeight(height - diff);
    },
    [_setKeyboardHeight, diff],
  );

  // use the above implemented keyboard calculation
  useOnKeyboardHeightUpdate(setKeyboardHeight);

  return [keyboardHeight, viewRefSetter];
}
```

```js
// KeyboardPaddedView.tsx
// 4. Wrap everything inside the Measured view for reusability
type Props = ViewProps & {};

function KeyboardPaddedView(props: Props): ReactElement {
  const { children, style, ...rest } = props;
  const [keyboardHeight, viewRefSetter] = useKeyboardPaddedHeightForView();
  const keyboardHeightStyle = {
    paddingBottom: keyboardHeight > 0 ? keyboardHeight : 0,
  };
  return (
    <View ref={viewRefSetter} style={[style, keyboardHeightStyle]} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
}

export default KeyboardPaddedView;
```

That's it, the KeyboardPaddedView can now be used accordingly, to avoid the keyboard, on both iOS and Android, which will now have the same behavior.

Honestly at this point I don't think anyone will read this, but just in case anyone does, sorry for the long solution, if anyone actually ends up reading and/or using this, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just Upgraded react-native-screen to latest version.

> yarn add react-native-screens

"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"

Comment: This did not fix the issue, rolling back to 3.10.2 hoping that it will do the job

Comment: having the issue with 3.20.0

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

**Before**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**After**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: This is the same answer which is already present

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, having both botton and top padding often result on the keyboard closing itself when opening. Took a while to discover that

Comment: top and bottom padding on what??

Answer (score 0):

if you're using react native version "0.64.*". Just set react-native-screens version to "3.4.0". Do not use "^" to avoid npm updated it. and it worked for me.