# Keyboard closes after every keypress in TextInput in react native?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-tsx, react-native-textinput

I am working on a react-native app in which I am facing a problem with the TextInput.
I am working on TSX(Typescript) and I have used react-native's textInput.
Whenever I press on a key on the keyboard, the keyboard automatically closes down.

I have provided the code below please review it.
Please seen the given video
https://vimeo.com/740689986

```
``  
<TextField value={firstNameValue}  fieldType='light'  label="First Name"   onChangeText={(value) => setFirstNameValue(value) } />
``
```

Comment: Code, maybe????

Comment: try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227463/react-native-textinput-closes-automatically-when-opened-on-android/71241027#71241027

Comment: @AdrianM I have updated the code plz review it.

Comment: @BiswanathTewari I have tried this but it is not working. Is there any other solution ?