# Keyboard keeps closing when typing on TextInput on android

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, react-navigation, textinput

We have a problem with our app on some android devices (working fine on iOS), whenever we try to type something on `TextInput` the keyboard keeps closing we tried so many solutions, we even thought the problem might be with react-native migration, so we migrated from react native `0.65` to `0.71.1`, it solved the problem at the first try but when I generated another bundle and tested it we faced the same problem again, on some android devices not all of them like always.

I tried the solutions on this issue [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33164) but didn't work, cleared the caches many times removed `node_modules` and re installed all but same problem.

We don't know exactly what is the problem, we getting claims from our users that they cannot change their informations on the app and stuff like that and that is really frustrating.

[preview](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExaXd0eTFvMTJndWFnYnVzc2puaWlhZDJneWhmeHNxN2I0M3lpYnh2dSZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/tOTHW5sIChRj2NCpml/giphy.gif)

Update:
Hope this helps but we found out that when moving to some screens it works then when moving to other screens it fails again.

I tried the solutions on this issue [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33164) but didn't work, cleared the caches many times removed `node_modules` and re installed all but same problem.

Comment: I've given you two links, one of these will work and address your queries : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227463/react-native-textinput-closes-automatically-when-opened-on-android
or 
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1342

Comment: @PratikPrakashBindage thank you but i tried both solutions setting react native screens to "~3.10.2" and android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" but still same problem. 
i found that we were importing navigation from @react-navigation/core, i will correct this and see again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.