# React Native realtime database build error

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

So I tried adding firebase database to an existing project and it kept throwing this gradle error, however when I made a new project and installed it, It worked fine, even the the project I'm currently working on was made only a couple months ago, so it's not that old of a project,

These are my dependencies:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.1",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.5.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.1.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.7",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.3.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.0",
"firebase": "^9.6.9",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-moment": "^1.1.1",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
```

and these are the logs I'm getting in console

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_database

Subproject ':react-native-firebase_database' has location '--\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_database'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file '--\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\android\build.gradle' from cache.

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s

at makeError (--\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)

at --\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

at async runOnAllDevices (--\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)

at async Command.handleAction (--\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically deleting the gradle cache fixed this issue for me, however gradlew clean didn't work either so I had to delete the cache folders

- On windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches`
- On Mac / UNIX: `~/.gradle/caches/`

[How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

Answer (score 0):

how you doing ?

Try to include those lines in android/settings.gradle.

```
include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
```

You can also set the compileSdkVersion to 30 or 31.
and targetSdkVersion 30 or above too.

Cheers

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue
Subproject ':react-native-firebase_app' has location '--\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_database'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file '--\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\android\build.gradle' from cache.