# Gradle fails with: Failed to load compiled script from classpath [.../.gradle/caches/jars-9/.../classes.jar]

Tags: android, gradle

After trying cleaning up the build cache (doing 'rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/' as suggested in [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)), Gradle stopped working entirely (no task would work). All of them immediate report the following error:

```
* Where:
Settings file '/.../android/settings.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Failed to load compiled script from classpath [/.../.gradle/caches/jars-9/.../classes.jar].
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42):

I found that the whole $HOME/.gradle folder needed to be deleted, otherwise Gradle would not work, looking for a missing jar. So, the solution:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle
```

Comment: This is non-obvious.