# Flutter build apk showring: Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateReleaseRFile'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, apk

I'm building a flutter app and while I try to build an apk using `flutter build apk`, this error is being thrown
[image]

I tried `flutter clean` and then `flutter build apk` but that didn't fix the problem either.
After clearing gradle cache, this showed up.

[image]

Any solutions come to mind? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share output from this command: flutter doctor -v

Comment: I checked and it's showing no issues were found @activout.se

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad gradle cache. Did you run out of disk space at some point?

See this StackOverflow question on how to clear the gradle cache: [How to clear gradle cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache)

Comment: No, there no issue with disk space. I already tried clearing the cache too. That's when the second error showed up. I've updated it in the original question.

Comment: "See compiler error output for details"... what is the full output from flutter build? By the way why are you not using flutter build appbundle?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout that your gradle plugin is compatible with your gradle version.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/5PU7loV.png) is the gradle version and after comparing it, it feels like it's correct.

Comment: For Flutter I would actually recommend staying on gradle 6.x, I think I use 6.7