# libfbjni.so needed by libexpo-av.so missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am working with `expo` (bare-workflow) project. While developing the application everything is working fine.
I tried creating the project build using `eas-cli`, but it is not working for me. The resultant build is not working on physical device.

Hence, I used this way of creating build :

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17460#issuecomment-1280632486

Here, I am getting this error.

I am not sure what is the main culprit behind this but any help would be appreciated.

I am using expo-av for animation.

Additional Logs :

```bash
Caused by: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/frank/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/frank/Desktop/work/parent/workshoppy/node_modules/expo-av/android/.cxx/Debug/4r382953/arm64-v8a expo-av}
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/frank/Desktop/work/parent/workshoppy/node_modules/expo-av/android/.cxx/Debug/4r382953/arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: '../../../../build/react-native-0.69.5-debug.aar/jni/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4r382953/obj/arm64-v8a/libexpo-av.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I have tried

```bash
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

but, it didn't worked

Comment: did you find a solution to it? I am facing exactly same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well. I do not have a solution. It seems that expo-av is not correctly specifying the dependencies in its own build. And that causes the build system randomly skip steps that are needed by expo-av.   This started happening since expo-av required C++ build step in  android app that use it

Comment: which version of `expo-av` are you using @wol and VP ? 

Also, I think we cannot get support from official repo because already it has many stale issues hence we need to find other workaround

Comment: Actually I solved it by cleaning build cache from Android Studio. You can try it with `gradlew cleanBuildCache` command or from Android Studio interface. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/5617627

Answer (score 0):

Cache is likely the culprit. There [is an issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17509) on the Expo repo about this.

Do `git clean -fdx` to fully blow away all local cache and rerun yarn.

If that does not work, verify you aren't placing your intermeditate build directive outside your repo. See comment on the thread about overriding gradle's buildDir value.