# Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:generateGeneralDebugRFile'. and Build Failed

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image: This is the error I'm facing...]
**This is an error I'm facing...**

**android/build.gradle**

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
    }
}
```

**This is my Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Fastlane",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.15",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-marquee": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.3.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
    def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fastlane"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        

    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

> 

- 

What I have tried...

- I think the commands which is necessary to solve the error I almost tried to solve...
- And also I have set the environment setup very properly as the react native setup docs says ...
- I have updated gradle version , kotlin version, react native version , npm version , node version etc...
- I have also updated Firebase app , Firebase message and Firebase.. where Firebase app and messages version should be same...
- I have also set up the SDK TOOLS, Android SDK in Android studio ...
- I have uninstalled the nodes, vs code and again reinstalled it but
  again facing the same issue i.e. Build Failed....

- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app was working fine before then, please follow below steps and check

1. Revert back all the changes you have made after that (if you changed versions of sdk, gradle, java, react-native etc)
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Delete build folders (`android/build` & `android/app/build`)
4. Recheck the `package.json` if the `react-native` version is as which was worked before
5. Run `npm install` or `yarn` to install packages
6. Clean (remove gradle cache like mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/10657559) and rebuild the app by adding the below changes to your `android/build.gradle` file

```html
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
     // ...
}
    
    
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    // ...  
}
```

Ref: [Fix and updates on Android build failures happening since Nov 4th 2022 #35210](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Answer (score 0):

In repositories tag of android/build.gradle

```
 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
 maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```